# REST API to get Frequent Sharepoint Sites programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile, my-site, microsoft-graph

Sharepoint Online offers a view of the frequent sites of the current user. It is available in the home page of the "My Site" of the user. I'm asking if there is a REST API (or something like) to get the **FREQUENT SITES** of the user programmatically?
Maybe also a Graph API query?

[image: frequent sites]

I know there is a way to get the LAST VISITED sites of the user but I don't mean that

`/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Web'&sortlist='ViewsRecent:descending,ViewsLifeTime:descending'&selectproperties='Title,Author,Url'`

And there is a way to get the FOLLOWED SITES but I don't mean neither that

`/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)`

Thank you

PS: I found the results in this call (sniffing the network calls of the page) but the host is strange...):
`https://northeurope1-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/feed?acronyms=true&start=0&count=12`

Comment: Maybe the Microsoft Graph API is able to do it.

Comment: Your search query doesn't list what _you_ viewed recent, but what anyone has viewed and you have access to. Having access to the beta insights API in the MS Graph via SP context would be useful indeed.

Comment: Microsoft Graph People Insignts seems a good candidate but it offers just: 1 ) Trending documents 2) Used documents 3) Shared documents but not frequent documents. To be honest I'm not so obsessed by frequent documents but the One Drive for Business page is offering it. So is quite natural to ask for it.

Comment: 2 years with no answers at all

Comment: Piero take a look to my answer, should work for you ( mark as solved if it does ) Thanks

Comment: I have add a new method to get the latest visited sites using graph, check it out ;)

Comment: The question was about "Frequent sites" but in your answer you're talking about "latest visited sites". I tried your query but I am not sure it gets frequent sites, like the sharepoint home page does. Thank you in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the GRAPH API**

- OPTION 1 ( Best & simplest option )

You can query the graph endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/Type eq spsite'&$orderby=lastUsed/lastAccessedDateTime desc`

It will return accurate information of the latest visited sites.

- OPTION 2

The [recently Visited Sites webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/tree/master/solution/src/webparts/recentlyVisitedSites) from the [sharepoint sp-starter-kit](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit), already shows the latest visited sites by the current user with the help of graph api.

This webpart gets the latest web pages the user has visited, on the endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/containerType eq 'Site' and ResourceVisualization/Type eq 'Web'`

Then, builds an array of unique site url based on the results returned by the query.

Please notice that *option 2's* results are always based on visited page items or files, then, if a user only visits the site homepage, such result wont be reflected in the query answer.

**Using Sharepoint REST API**

If you are looking for an alternative way of retrieving  the latest visited sites, you can query the below endpoint ( replace top with number of desired results )

`/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/recent??mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=${top}&acronyms=true`

And dont forget to add the additional header `SPHome-ClientType`.
Here is a javascript example:

```
return await (await this.httpCli.get(
        `/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/recent??mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=${top}&acronyms=true`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        { headers: { "SPHome-ClientType": "SharePointIOS" } })
      ).json();
```

PS1: [feel free to test the microsoft graph api here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview)

PS2: This sharepoint rest api will be exposed and documented some day in graph api, [as described on this github thread.](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1689)