# SharePoint Rest API : Recent SharePoint Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

I am currently using the following endpoints to access user specific sites (followed, frequent and suggested)

```
/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed
/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/recent
/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/suggested
```

Both the `/followed` and `/suggested` work perfectly well, however the `/recent` is only giving me this output :

```js
{
    "HttpStatus": "InternalServerError",
    "ErrorMessage": "Office graph is disabled.",
    "ErrorCode": 500011
}
```

According to brannmar (and the accepted answer) and after testing, the `/recent` endpoint does work with the added header `SPHome-ClientType: SharePointIOS` but from what he is saying, I won't be able to use this in a prodution environment.

I don't feel strongly about this endpoint particularly but I have not found any endpoint in Graph or the actual SharePoint Rest API that does something remotely similar.

I found these endpoints in various posts :

[REST API to get Frequent Sharepoint Sites programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231015/rest-api-to-get-frequent-sharepoint-sites-programmatically)

[How to programmatically get Frequent Sharepoint Sites using REST API?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/06c846b2-3dad-481d-b9ae-7a1f28d34a67/how-to-programmatically-get-frequent-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[Office 365: The New SharePoint Homepage](https://sharepoint.protiviti.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=305)

The second post is the most interesting as you can see the issue was already here in dec-17 / jan-18. The OP suggests he posted a feedback on https://office365.uservoice.com but I can't seem to find it.

I have also tried using the endpoint used by the SharePoint Portal (https://<tenant>/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx) but I get an Unauthorized Access Exception because i don't know how to authenticate for this call.

Uri: https://northeurope1-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/recent

The call is made only once (then it is cached probably in a hidden list on the user MySite) and uses a JWT Bearer Token (mine doesn't seem to work, but I guess it's normal since it's a token for my tenant)

I'm open to any suggestion !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if you have gotten a answer to this question some other way but here is a possible solution to your Office graph is disabled problem.

By simply adding an extra header to your request it should solve your problem.

```
SPHome-ClientType: SharePointIOS
```

I dont know why this works but it does. And also this it not a documented API from Microsoft so I would not use it in production. I have noticed multiple 500 errors when using it.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the GRAPH API**

The [recently Visited Sites webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/tree/master/solution/src/webparts/recentlyVisitedSites) from the [sharepoint sp-starter-kit](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit), already shows the latest visited sites by the current user with the help of graph api.

This webpart gets the latest web pages the user has visited, on the endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/containerType eq 'Site' and ResourceVisualization/Type eq 'Web'`

Then, builds an array of unique site url based on the results returned by the query.

You can follow the same approach in your scenario, **HOWEVER,** these results are always based on visited page items or files, then, if a user only visits the site homepage, such result wont be reflected in the query answer.

**CONCLUSION: use Sharepoint REST API**

If you are looking for an accurate result array of latest visited sites, best thing is to query the below enpoint ( replace top with number of desired results )

`/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/recent??mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=${top}&acronyms=true`

And dont forget to add the additional header `SPHome-ClientType`.
Here is a javascript example:

```
return await (await this.httpCli.get(
        `/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/recent??mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=${top}&acronyms=true`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        { headers: { "SPHome-ClientType": "SharePointIOS" } })
      ).json();
```

PS1: [feel free to test the microsoft graph api here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview)

PS2: This sharepoint rest api will be exposed and documented some day in graph api, [as described on this github thread.](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1689)